# CDI cannot retrieve servlet responde using @Context annotation

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jax-rs, cdi

I have a jax-rs web service returning json, and I'd like to add cors headers to it.

so I Have the following class:

```
[...]
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
[...]

@Stateful
@Path("/grupo")
@RequestScoped
@TransactionAttribute
public class GrupoEndpoint
{

   @Context
   private HttpServletResponse response;

    @GET
    public List<Grupo> listAll()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final List<Grupo> results = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM Grupo x").getResultList();
        // here response is null!!!
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
        return results;
    }
```

But response is always null, is there something I might be missing?

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but annotating your class as a CDI bean with RequestScoped and an EJB with Stateful annotation is never a good idea...if your class doesn't hold any other stateful property, I suggest to mark it as Stateless, and remove the RequestScoped annotation

Answer (score 2):

@Stateful conflicts with @RequestScoped. @RequestScoped means a new instance of the resource is created for each request, while @Stateful would result in the same instance being shared between requests. If @Stateful takes precedence, you are trying to inject request-scoped variable (HttpServletRequest) to a singleton-scoped resource, which may not work. You can try injecting it into listAll() as a method parameter (`public List<Grupo> listAll(@Context HttpServletRequest request)`).

But you should not be adding headers via HttpServletResponse anyway - instead you should declare your method as follows:

```
@GET
public Response listAll()
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final List<Grupo> results = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM Grupo x").getResultList();
    return Response.ok(new GenericEntity<List<Grupo>>(results) {})
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
            .build();
}
```